# C++ multiple numbers from a single variable

Tags: c++, variables, controller

Basically, I have this controller that I’m reading data off of, and when you press the 1 button, it outputs an 8 to the computer, when you press the 2, it outputs a 16, when you press the 3, it outputs a 32, when you press the 4, it outputs a 64, when you press the 5, it outputs a 128 and when you press the 6, it outputs a 256 right? Well here's when it gets interesting. When you press, say the 1 and the 2 buttons together, it outputs a 24, if you press the 3 and 1, it outputs 40! It's adding all the buttons together! Is there any way I could write another part of code that would separate out and have it say which buttons are being pressed to make this sum? I was thinking that I could just come up with an if statement for all the combos, but that’s 36 if statements per controller and I’m using two at a time. Please help!

Shadow

Edit:
Well my code is quite simple; I’m using a pre-built SDK so I’m still struggling to un-earth everything there is in it. I have figured out is that I can print this int called "buttons" and that’s the one variable I’m talking about. Here’s the code (well at least the part that I need help deciphering):

cout << acd.controllers[0].buttons << endl;

I’m still relatively new (I know the basics and some intermediate stuff too) to C++ and am trying to figure everything out and I couldn’t find anything in Google that could help me with this problem.

@Angew: What handle are you talking about?
@Peter: I thought so, I just have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: It's OR'ing the bits.

Comment: Add comments to answers, don't edit them into the question - there's no notification for them there. I meant the "handle" bit as a verb - a placeholder for your action. In other words: "Button number `bit - 2` was pressed, put your relevant code here."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
for (size_t bit = 3; bit <= 8; ++bit)
{
  if (output & (1 << bit))
  {
    handle_case_that_button_was_pressed(bit - 2);
  }
}
```

Where `output` is the output from the controller, and `handle_case_that_button_was_pressed(n)` is a placeholder for your code dealing with the fact that button nr. `n` was pressed.

**EDIT**

An example to output all buttons pressed:

```
std::vector<size_t> buttonsPressed;

for (size_t bit = 3; bit <= 8; ++bit)
{
  if (output & (1 << bit))
  {
     buttonsPressed.push_back(bit - 2);
  }
}

if (buttonsPressed.empty())
  std::cout << "No buttons pressed\n";
else {
  std::cout << "Button";
  if (buttonsPressed.size() > 1)
    std::cout << 's';
  std::cout << ' ';
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < buttonsPressed.size(); ++idx) {
    std::cout << buttonsPressed[idx] << ", "
  }
  std::cout << "are pressed.\n";
}
```

For quick demo, I used indexing to traverse the vector. That's not how you would normally do it - you'd use a range-based for loop, if available, or iterators.

Comment: you can probably go one better and write your for loop as: for (size_t bit = 1 << 3; bit <= 1 << 8; bit <<= 1)

Comment: @doron Well, the number of the pressed button would be more difficult to retrieve then.

Comment: @Angew: Alright, i'm new to this forum. And I see! I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: Alright, I tryed implimenting the code, and just changing the handle to outputing like this; for (size_t bit = 3; bit <= 8; ++bit){ if (acd.controllers[0].buttons & (1 << bit)){ cout << acd.controllers[0].buttons; } } And it outputed (when I pressed multiple buttons) both of the bits added together but then coppied as many times as buttons I had pressed. ie: if I pressed 1, 2, and 3, and it outputed "565656."

Comment: @user2497479 Yes, that's precisely what should happen. What are you after, exactly?

Comment: Ohhh well good then! That means I implemented it correctly haha :D
I was hoping for somthing that could interpert that answer and say "buttons 1 & 3 are being pressed." type thing.

Comment: @Shadow2917 I added an example of use. I hope it's clearer how to use this now.

Comment: Okay now I gotcha! Thank ya much for the help Angew.

Comment: @Shadow2917 Once you feel your question here on StackOverflow is solved, you should accept the answer which solved it (by clicking the tick mark next to it). That's how SO works. You can read more about it in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

To get data from bits which have been bitwise OR'd together you need to use bitwise AND:

```
int ONE = 8;
int TWO = 16;
int THREE = 32;
int FOUR = 64;

int pressed = ONE | THREE; // pressed is now 40

if(pressed & ONE) {
    // handle 1 is pressed
}
if(pressed & TWO) {
    // handle 2 is pressed
}
// etc
```

Comment: Well my code is quite simple; I’m using a pre-built SDK so I’m still struggling to un-earth everything there is in it. I have figured out is that I can print this int called "buttons" and that’s the one variable I’m talking about. Here’s the code:

cout << acd.controllers[0].buttons << endl;

I’m still relatively new (I know the basics and some intermediate stuff too) to C++ and am trying to figure everything out and I couldn’t find anything in Google that could help me with this problem.
@Peter: I thought so, I just have no idea how to do that.